# Sequence of datetimes except weekends Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to create a sequence of datetime object but excluding weekends. So far I've successfully created a sequence of dates from any given start date to end date, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to exclude weekends:

```
# Generate sequence of dates
startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
nb_days = (endDate - startDate).days + 1  # + 1 because range is exclusive
dates = [startDate + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(nb_days)]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `isoweekday()` function returns the day of the week, with 1 a Monday.

```
[d for d in dates if not d.isoweekday() in [6,7]]
```

Comment: brilliant solution. In addition, given your Stackoverflow profile, you might be able to help me a little bit further with my problem. How would I exclude all non-trading days between start/end?

Comment: @Apollo If you have a list of holidays, then just `[d for d in dates if not d in holidays]`

Comment: yea so there's no py lib to generate a list of dates?

Comment: @Apollo Dates are location-specific and vary year-to-year. So you'll need a list of holidays wherever you are.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite nicely with the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/) library's [rrule](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html#rrule-examples).

Example:

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR

result = rrule(
  DAILY,
  byweekday=(MO,TU,WE,TH,FR),
  dtstart=parse(start),
  until=parse(end)
)
print(list(result))
```

Example output:

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 22, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 23, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 24, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 25, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 28, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 30, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 31, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 4, 0, 0)]
```