# i want to get all dates exclude weekends between two dates in python

Tags: python

I want to get all the dates between two dates excluding weekends dates.
Below is the format of dates:

```
last_date = '2019-01-21'
curr_date = '2019-02-04'
```

Comment: And... so? Which is the question?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you've tried up to this point?

Comment: Very similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167797/sequence-of-datetimes-except-weekends-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequence of datetimes except weekends Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167797/sequence-of-datetimes-except-weekends-python)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [date.weekday()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

> Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday
>   is 6.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

start_dt = date(2019,1,21)
end_dt = date(2019,2,4)

weekdays = [5,6]
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    if dt.weekday() not in weekdays:                    # to print only the weekdates
        print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

EDIT:

Using [date.isoweekday()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

> Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 1 and Sunday
>   is 7.

```
weekdays = [6,7]
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    if dt.isoweekday() not in weekdays:
        print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

OUTPUT:

```
2019-01-21
2019-01-22
2019-01-23
2019-01-24
2019-01-25
2019-01-28
2019-01-29
2019-01-30
2019-01-31
2019-02-01
2019-02-04
```

Comment: Does one need the `int` in `int((date2 - date1).days + 1)`? When does `.days` not return an integer?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quite nicely with the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/) library's [rrule](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html#rrule-examples).

Example:

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR

last_date = '2019-01-21'
curr_date = '2019-02-04'

result = rrule(
  DAILY,
  byweekday=(MO,TU,WE,TH,FR),
  dtstart=parse(last_date),
  until=parse(curr_date)
)
print(list(result))
```

Result:

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 22, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 23, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 24, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 25, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 28, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 30, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 31, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 4, 0, 0)]
```