# find non weekend holiday

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first query. I have recently started learning about Python and still long way to go. I am practicing pandas and below is a problem I am working on. I found the solution but think the code is not optimal, so can you please help to review the code and let me know how can I optimized this further.

Problem:
Find a non weekend holiday for each currency each month.

Data:
I have a CSV in below format

```
Columns      :   Currency | YearandMonth | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |......| 31 |
Row 1 Data   :   EUR      | 202101       | H |   | H |   |   |   |......| H  |   
Row 2 Data   :   EUR      | 202101       |   | H | H |   |   |   |......| H  |   
Row 3 Data   :   EUR      | 202101       |   |   |   |   | H |   |......| H  |  
.
.
.
```

Similar rows for USD, NZD etc.

Details:
Where H is mentioned its a holiday including weekend. As mentioned earlier aim is to find non weekend holiday for each currency.

Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import calendar

df = pd.read_csv('HSCFHoliday.csv')
df = df.fillna('')

try:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        day = 0
        while day < len(row):
            strDate = ''
            if day >= 2:
                if row[day] == 'H':
                    if len(df.columns[day]) == 1:
                        strDate = str(row[1]) + '0' + str(df.columns[day])
                    else:
                        strDate = str(row[1]) + str(df.columns[day])
                    strFDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, '%Y%m%d').weekday()
                    strDay = str.strip(calendar.day_name[strFDate])
                    if (str.lower(strDay) != 'sunday') and (str.lower(strDay) != 'saturday'):
                        print(str(row[0]) + ',' + str(row[1]) + str(df.columns[day]) + ',' + str(strDay))                    
            day = day + 1
except Exception:
    print('Got expcetion')
```

Output :

```
EUR,2021011,Friday                                                
EUR,2021042,Friday                                                
EUR,2021045,Monday                                                
NZD,2021011,Friday                                                
NZD,2021014,Monday                                                
NZD,2021028,Monday
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sequence of datetimes except weekends Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167797/sequence-of-datetimes-except-weekends-python)

Comment: This question is probably better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com. However be sure to take their [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read their [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page before posting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for advice optimizing code; it should be asked on Code Review instead.